# can you suggest me better solutions for this in C++ inline-assembly?

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, inline-assembly

i am learning assembly and i started experiments on SSE and MMX registers within the Digital-Mars C++ compiler (intel sytanx more easily readable). I have finished a program that takes var_1 as a value and converts it to the var_2 number system(this is in 8 bit for now. will expand it to 32 64 128 later) . Program does this by two ways:

1. `__asm` inlining
2. Usual C++ way of %(modulo) operator.

Question: Can you tell me more efficient way to use xmm0-7 and mm0-7 registers and can you tell me how to exchange exact bytes of them with al,ah... 8 bit registers?

Usual %(modulo) operator in the C++ usual way is very slow in comparison with __asm   on my computer(pentium-m centrino 2.0GHz).
If you can tell me how to get rid of division instruction in __asmm, it will be even faster.

When i run the program it gives me:

```
(for the values: var_1=17,var_2=2,all loops are 200M times)

17 is 10001 in number system 2
__asm(clock)...........: 7250    <------too bad. it is 8-bit calc.
C++(clock).............: 12250   <------not very slow(var_2 is a power of 2)


(for the values: var_1=33,var_2=7,all loops are 200M times)
33 is 45 in number system 7
 __asm(clock)..........: 2875   <-------not good. it is 8-bit calc.
 C++(clock)............: 6328   <----------------really slow(var_2 is not a power of 2)
```

The second C++ code(the one with % operator): /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
t1=clock();//reference time
for(int i=0;i<200000000;i++)
{
    y=x;
    counter=0;
    while(y>g)
    {   

        var_3[counter]=y%g;
        y/=g;
        counter++;
    }

     var_3[counter]=y%g;
}   
t2=clock();//final time
```

_asm code:////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     __asm  // i love assembly in some parts of C++
        {

        pushf   //here does register backup
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push edi

            mov eax,0h      //this will be outer loop counter init to zero
            //init of medium-big registers to zero
            movd xmm0,eax    //cannot set to immediate constant: xmm0=outer loop counter 
            shufps xmm0,xmm0,0h //this makes all bits zero
            movd xmm1,eax
            movd xmm2,eax   
            shufps xmm1,xmm1,0h
            shufps xmm2,xmm2,0h
            movd xmm2,eax 
            shufps xmm3,xmm3,0h//could have made pxor xmm3,xmm3(single instruction)
            //init complete(xmm0,xmm1,xmm2,xmm3 are zero)

            movd xmm1,[var_1] //storing variable_1 to register
            movd xmm2,[var_2] //storing var_2 to register    
            lea ebx,var_3     //calculate var_3 address
            movd xmm3,ebx     //storing var_3's address to register
            for_loop:
            mov eax,0h      
            //this line is index-init to zero(digit array index)
            movd edx,xmm2
            mov cl,dl       //this is the var_1 stored in cl
            movd edx,xmm1
            mov al,dl       //this is the var_2 stored in al
            mov edx,0h
            dng:
                mov ah,00h      //preparation for a 8-bit division
                div cl          //divide

                movd ebx,xmm3   //get var_3 address
                add ebx,edx     //i couldnt find a way to multiply with 4
                add ebx,edx     //so i added 4 times ^^
                add ebx,edx     //add   
                add ebx,edx     //last adding
                //below, mov [ebx],ah is the only memory accessing instruction
                mov [ebx],ah    //(8 bit)this line is equivalent to var_3[i]=remainder


                inc edx         //i++;
                cmp al,00h      //is division zero?
            jne dng             //if no, loop again

            //here edi register has the number of digits

            movd eax,xmm0       //get the outer loop counter from medium-big register
            add eax,01h         //j++;
            movd xmm0,eax       //store the new counter to medium-big register
            cmp eax,0BEBC200h           //is j<(200,000,000) ?
            jb for_loop     //if yes, go loop again
            mov [var_3_size],edx //now we have number of digits too!
         //here does registers revert back to old values
        pop edi
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        popf     

        }
```

Whole code://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <cmath>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
    {

    srand(time(0));


    clock_t t1=clock();
    clock_t t2=clock();

    int var_1=17;  //number itself
    int var_2=2;   //number system
    int var_3[100];  //digits to be showed(maximum 100 as seen )
    int var_3_size=0;//asm block will decide what will the number of  digits be

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
    var_3[i]=0; //here we initialize digits to zeroes
    }


    t1=clock();//reference time to take
     __asm  // i love assembly in some parts of C++
        {

        pushf   //here does register backup
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push edi

            mov eax,0h      //this will be outer loop counter init to zero
            //init of medium-big registers to zero
            movd xmm0,eax    //cannot set to immediate constant: xmm0=outer loop counter 
            shufps xmm0,xmm0,0h //this makes all bits zero
            movd xmm1,eax
            movd xmm2,eax   
            shufps xmm1,xmm1,0h
            shufps xmm2,xmm2,0h
            movd xmm2,eax 
            shufps xmm3,xmm3,0h
            //init complete(xmm0,xmm1,xmm2,xmm3 are zero)

            movd xmm1,[var_1] //storing variable_1 to register
            movd xmm2,[var_2] //storing var_2 to register    
            lea ebx,var_3     //calculate var_3 address
            movd xmm3,ebx     //storing var_3's address to register
            for_loop:
            mov eax,0h      
            //this line is index-init to zero(digit array index)
            movd edx,xmm2
            mov cl,dl       //this is the var_1 stored in cl
            movd edx,xmm1
            mov al,dl       //this is the var_2 stored in al
            mov edx,0h
            dng:
                mov ah,00h      //preparation for a 8-bit division
                div cl          //divide

                movd ebx,xmm3   //get var_3 address
                add ebx,edx     //i couldnt find a way to multiply with 4
                add ebx,edx     //so i added 4 times ^^
                add ebx,edx     //add   
                add ebx,edx     //last adding
                //below, mov [ebx],ah is the only memory accessing instruction
                mov [ebx],ah    //(8 bit)this line is equivalent to var_3[i]=remainder


                inc edx         //i++;
                cmp al,00h      //is division zero?
            jne dng             //if no, loop again

            //here edi register has the number of digits

            movd eax,xmm0       //get the outer loop counter from medium-big register
            add eax,01h         //j++;
            movd xmm0,eax       //store the new counter to medium-big register
            cmp eax,0BEBC200h           //is j<(200,000,000) ?
            jb for_loop     //if yes, go loop again
            mov [var_3_size],edx //now we have number of digits too!
         //here does registers revert back to old values
        pop edi
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        popf     

        }
    t2=clock(); //finish time
    printf("\n assembly_inline(clocks): %i  for the 200 million calculations",(t2-t1)); 

        printf("\n value %i(in decimal) is: ",var_1);
for(int i=var_3_size-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("%i",var_3[i]);
}
printf(" in the number system: %i \n",var_2);




//and: more readable form(end easier)
    int counter=var_3_size;
    int x=var_1;
    int g=var_2;
    int y=x;// backup
t1=clock();//reference time

for(int i=0;i<200000000;i++)
{
    y=x;
    counter=0;
    while(y>g)
    {   

        var_3[counter]=y%g;
        y/=g;
        counter++;
    }

     var_3[counter]=y%g;
}

t2=clock();//final time
printf("\n C++(clocks): %i  for the 200 million calculations",(t2-t1)); 

printf("\n value %i(in decimal) is: ",x);
for(int i=var_3_size-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("%i",var_3[i]);
}
printf(" in the number system: %i \n",g);
return 0;
```

}

edit:
this is 32-bit version

```
    void get_digits_asm()
{
    __asm
    {

        pushf       //couldnt store this in other registers 
        movd xmm0,eax//storing in xmm registers instead of pushing
        movd xmm1,ebx//
        movd xmm2,ecx//
        movd xmm3,edx//
        movd xmm4,edi//end of push backups

        mov eax,[variable_x]
        mov ebx,[number_system]
        mov ecx,0h
        mov edi,0h

        begin_loop:
        mov edx,0h
        div ebx             
        lea edi,digits  
        mov [edi+ecx*4],edx
        add ecx,01h
        cmp eax,ebx
        ja begin_loop

        mov edx,0
        div ebx
        lea edi,digits
        mov [edi+ecx*4],edx
        inc ecx
        mov [digits_total],ecx


        movd edi,xmm4//pop edi
        movd edx,xmm3//pop edx
        movd ecx,xmm2//pop ecx
        movd ebx,xmm1//pop ebx
        movd eax,xmm0//pop eax
        popf            
    }

}
```

Comment: Your method to set the xmm registers to zero seems odd, why not use `pxor xmm0,xmm0` etc? edit: actually the whole code is a bit odd..

Comment: did you mean the shuffle part? You are right. I didnt learn pxor yet :D

Comment: Hmm. Xor is even more faster. yes

Comment: but they are out of loop. Thank you anyway

Comment: i just wondered how it is to use new registers as an array. I couldnt use them as 8-bit array yet. i am trying. Thats why it is odd. Even more odd to me.

Comment: i started with 8086 emulator. i tried int 21. didnt work. so i inlined in C++ :D. Did i do a good thing? I mean, i want to assemble-make only the critical areas of my program. Am i right?

Comment: Your code is way too long for modulo in loop in assembly.

Comment: There isnt a single instruction for this. I made this to use memory as less as possible. Thats why i swapped things in registers. People said memory latency is ten times of cpu cycle generally

Comment: I am thinking of making programs like this, then inlining in some header files then using those headers to help my java program work different. Do i need open-source files for that?

Comment: Inline assembler doesnt accept multiplying the index with 4 for array-access. I added 4 times for that. Did i do good? i wanted to make something like this: lea edx,[var_3+4*di] . But compiler didnt accept that

Comment: Why not just use a real assembler to learn assembly? NASM has a very consistent and intel-like syntax, but there are various other options, too.

Comment: Please keep the chatter in question lower and comments focused on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be much simpler of course: (modeled after the C++ version, does not include pushes and pops, and not tested)

```
  mov esi,200000000
_bigloop:
  mov eax,[y]
  mov ebx,[g]
  lea edi,var_3
  ; eax = y
  ; ebx = g
  ; edi = var_3
  xor ecx,ecx
  ; ecx = counter
_loop:
  xor edx,edx
  div ebx
  mov [edi+ecx*4],edx
  add ecx,1
  test eax,eax
  jnz _loop
  sub esi,1
  jnz _bigloop
```

But I would be surprised if it was faster than the C++ version, and in fact it'll almost certainly be slower if the base is a power of two - all sane compilers know how to turn a division and/or modulo by a power of two into bitshifts and bitwise ands.

---

Here's a version that uses ab 8-bit division. Similar caveats apply, but now the division could even overflow (if `y / g` is more than 255).

```
  mov esi,200000000
_bigloop:
  mov eax,[y]
  mov ebx,[g]
  lea edi,var_3
  ; eax = y
  ; ebx = g
  ; edi = var_3
  xor ecx,ecx
  ; ecx = counter
_loop:
  div bl
  mov [edi+ecx],ah
  add ecx,1
  and eax,0xFF
  jnz _loop
  sub esi,1
  jnz _bigloop
```

Comment: i put push and pops outside the loops

Comment: This code takes %20  more time(my bloated code 2800 cycles, this code 3600 cycles). But my cpu is 2.0 GHz laptop-centrino Pentium-M. And ram is pc-400

Comment: Anyway, this is %80 more readable and  not time-consuming. I mean, my code is faster but i am not fast :D

Comment: Your code is doing 32 bit calc. Am i right? Mine is just 8 bit calc. But uses 128 bit registers :D

Comment: It's probably slower because it does a 32bit division

Comment: I will make my code 32 bit in a week. Thank you and see you a week later.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I made a 8-bit version, you could try that one as well if you like

Comment: 4500 cycles. omg even slower. This means, when i get to the 32 bit, it will be more faster :D

Comment: Then this must be about data aligning or something

Comment: im planning doing these calculations in xmm0..7 in parallel(packed). Does it increse speed significantly?

Comment: Something like:printf_8bit, printf_16bit, printf_32bit ..... sqrt_8bit() inverse_sqrt_8bit_parallel() ......

Comment: There is no vectorized integer division/modulo, by the way. I don't really see any reason for this to be slower than your code though, that really surprises me. Paging Mystical :)

Comment: maybe because of my laptop changing cpu frequency 2.0GHz to 1Ghz dynamically i dont know

Comment: Make it stop changing then. You can't benchmark reliably if it does that. And this code shouldn't overheat it, it doesn't use enough functional units and it definitely doesn't have a high enough throughput.

Comment: I think i need to clean cpu-fan. Shuts down itself too

Comment: i bet u get less than 1000 cycles for all of the loops(on single core)

Comment: your cpu has super-shuffle ability which makes my algorithm faster ^^   http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~franzf/teaching/slides-18-645-simd.pdf page-5

Comment: That's the 45nm version IIRC. But your algorithm doesn't rely on shuffling anyway..

Comment: Yes i just saw that part was out of loop

Comment: So I timed it, the 8bit version takes 26.7 cycles (per iteration of the inner loop) on average on my CPU. The 32bit version takes 51.5 cycles. Both with y=33, g=7. I don't really like these parameters, they make the inner loop take too few iterations.

Comment: i gave 3600,2800,4500 like outputs in terms of C++ clock() function subtractions . not the real cpu clocks. 26.7 cycle/loop you are saying you used some profiling software to get exact cpu-cycles?

Comment: if you try var_1=255 and var_2=2, you can achieve       8 inner-loop count

Comment: I used `__rdtsc`, and I didn't use it in an entirely accurate way and not running in realtime, but I figured that with such a high iteration count it would be accurate enough for this purpose.

Comment: you mean cache-hit? The rdtsc is assembly or C++?

Comment: I mean all sorts of effects.. anyway with 255 and 2, I get 143 cycles for the 32bit version and 131 for the 8bit version. `rdtsc` is assembly, but I used the intrinsic function in C++.

Comment: i searched for rdtsc and found that it can reset itself very quickly especially in fast cpu's. I mean the counter reaches boundaries fast. So this is only for non-benchmarkings i think.

Comment: 10 * 200000000 (if counting the number of times the inner loop is started), and the timestamp doesn't overflow that much does it? It's a 64bit integer so it should take a while..

Comment: you are right. i made all calculations                      1*outer_loop(which is 200M)*inner_loop(which is 8 for the 255 and 2)  equals 1.6 Billion total loops. You made 2 Billions